# I'm a U.S. citizen & my spouse is a Spanish national with dual citizenship Spain/U.S. does the 90/180 day Schengen rule apply to me?

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, spain, eu-family-member

I'm a U.S. citizen and my spouse is a Spanish national with dual citizenship (Spain/U.S.).  When traveling to Spain together does the 90/180 day Schengen rule apply to me?  If not and I'm allowed longer stays do I need to apply for anything to allow the longer stays?

Answer (score 2):

> When traveling to Spain together [with a Spanish national] does the 90/180 day Schengen rule apply to me?

When travelling with (or joining) an EU citizen the 90/180 day Schengen rule **does not** apply to you.

Since you, as a US citizen, do not require a visa to enter the Schengen Area, you do **not** require a [Visa for family members of a citizen of the Union](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/dublin/en/ServiciosConsulares/Paginas/Consular/Visados-para-familiares-de-ciudadanos-de-la-Union.aspx).

> do I need to apply for anything to allow the longer stays?

For a stay longer than **3 months** in Spain, you must must apply for a **residence card of a family member of a citizen of the European Union**.

This must be done **within** three months of your date of entry into Spain, at the Non-nationals Office. You will be will immediately be given a certificate of application for the residence card.

**Note**: I could find no exact information what a spanish citizen, returning to Spain for longer than 3 months, must do. I assume residence registration at the relevant local police station.

---

**Sources**:

- [Residence - Acquiring residence](https://administracion.gob.es/pag_Home/en/Tu-espacio-europeo/derechos-obligaciones/ciudadanos/residencia/obtencion-residencia/info-general.html) (Directorate-General of Public Governance)

  - [Registering your residence - EU Citizens](https://administracion.gob.es/pag_Home/en/Tu-espacio-europeo/derechos-obligaciones/ciudadanos/residencia/obtencion-residencia/inscribirte-residente.html)

    - this **does not** apply to spanish citizens
  - [Registering EU family members](https://administracion.gob.es/pag_Home/en/Tu-espacio-europeo/derechos-obligaciones/ciudadanos/residencia/obtencion-residencia/registrar-familiares.html)

    - this **does not** apply to family members who are spanish citizens
  - [Registering non-EU family members](https://administracion.gob.es/pag_Home/en/Tu-espacio-europeo/derechos-obligaciones/ciudadanos/residencia/obtencion-residencia/inscribir-familiares-no-ue.html)

    - this **does** apply to family members of spanish citizens
- [Visas for family members of a citizen of the Union](https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/dublin/en/ServiciosConsulares/Paginas/Consular/Visados-para-familiares-de-ciudadanos-de-la-Union.aspx)
- [BOE.es - BOE-A-2007-4184 Royal Decree 240/2007, of February 16, on the entry, free movement and residence in Spain of citizens of the Member States of the European Union and of other States party to the Agreement on the European Economic Area.](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2007-4184)

Comment: It’s also worth noting that depending on the duration of stay and/or activities during the stay, both OP and their spouse may have to register, file returns and pay taxes in Spain (in addition to the US).

Comment: Why lead with “When travelling with (or joining) an EU citizen the 90/180 day Schengen rule does not apply to you.” when you write further down that EU freedom of movement rules do not apply in this case?

Comment: @Relaxed The answer doesn't state anywhere that the EU freedom of movement rules do not apply in this case.

Comment: True, my bad, I read too fast and assumed you understood your sources, which isn't usually the case. Let me ask you this then: Do you think freedom of movement rules do apply? Why?

Comment: @Relaxed I do understand my sources, thats why I included the *Royal Decree 240/2007*, which is the spanish implmentation of the Freedom of movement directive, where in Article 6 (2) and 7 (2) the family members are handeled. The *Visa for family members of a citizen of the Union* link also states explicidly that it applies to family members of a spanish national in multiple places. Note also that the OP is **not** asking about this, but what he has to do to stay longer or if the 90 days rule applies to him when travelling with his spanish spouce.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Where does it say that? Spanish law may have such provision (haven't been able to find a solid source one way or the other) but the freedom of movement directive emphatically does *not* apply and the first sentence of your answer is misleading in that regard. And it is obviously very relevant to what the OP would have to do to stay longer than 90 days as, absent a specific provision in Spanish law, the rule does apply as far as EU law is concerned.

Comment: @Relaxed The *Royal Decree 240/2007* doesn't explicidly state it, but the link to the *Visa for family members of a citizen of the Union* (meantioned in Article 4 (2) of the Royal Decree) does: *Copy of the passport of the EU/EEA/Swiss citizen (**or also DNI, if he/she is Spanish**) attested by notary public*. That is why I added that link to the answer.

Comment: OK, makes sense. I still think this really need to be clarified in the answer. As it stands, you seem to suggest that freedom of movement and the directive do apply (which is not the case). You quote several pages on registration which you claim apply in this case but do not contain anything confirming that and then this visa application page which also does not obviously apply (as the OP is a US citizen and wouldn't need a visa for a short-stay).

Comment: Now, the visa application page does provide roundabout evidence that Spain treats its own citizen in the same way as EU citizens, which is relevant but this ought to be explained in the answer.

Comment: @Relaxed Plus the lack of a special residence permit type for family members of spanish nationals (that Italy and Germany for example have). I at least found none this morning. Remember this is not a law forum, where such questions should be delt with.

Comment: @Relaxed, Mark Johnson: the Spanish law linked in this answer shows that the provision that purported to amend another law to apply EU free movement law to family of Spanish citizens was nullified by the _Tribunal Supremo_ in 2010.  Now I think I've seen a subsequent legal instrument restoring that provision, but I can't find it now.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Well, you chose to deal with it. If you don't want to suggest you know for a fact that this is the case, you need to rewrite your answer. If you prefer to remove any reference to EU law, you can do that too. But if you bring it up, it deserves an explanation.